# Orace - CASE ... WHEN IN, etc. syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
select case myFunction(someField) when in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') then 'Option1' 
when someOtherField = 'Val4' then 'Option2' else null end as someColumn
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037) also has some examples...

Comment: I'm not sure that duplicate explains why the pseudocode is wrong. You can't use `in` with that form of [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm): "In a simple CASE expression, Oracle Database searches for the first WHEN ... THEN pair for which expr is equal to comparison_expr...". Your 'in' i not equal to anything. So you need to use the searched CASE syntax, which the duplicate does show. The pseudocode has a mix of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when myFunction(someField) in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') then 'Option1' when someOtherField = 'Val4' then 'Option2' else null end as someColumn from dual
```